# Vuescan says 16 bits / pixel, photoshop says 8. Who stole my bits?

Tags: photoshop, scanning

I scan a negative in VueScan, setting input bits/pixel to 16, and output as a raw file, also with bits/pixel set to 16. I turn on raw DNG format.

Open in Bridge (which open in Adobe Camera Raw), then hit 'Open' to proceed to Photoshop.

I find myself with a 8 bit photoshop document.

At what point did I lose 8 bits?

Could it be that my Epson V800 Photo only produces 8 bits / pixel in the first place?

Comment: "Who stole my bits?" – LOL.

Comment: What happens if you save in TIFF or PNG format?  Can you provide a sample DNG?

Answer (score 5):

It's an Adobe Camera Raw setting. PS can't edit a raw file (dng) so it first opens in ACR, and that's where it is being reduced to 8bit.

Click on the file specs at the bottom of the ACR window, or the gear icon in the upper right.

[image]

Then change the setting to 16bit and open the file in PS.

[image]

Next time it should open with 16bit selected, but keep an eye on it as sometimes it reverts (e.g. with an ACR update or something).